# WebJobs integration with logic apps

Tags: powershell

I need to run a Powershell script which calls a Perl command to execute the file. 
This is my Powershell command:

```
parm($scriptpath,$inputpath,$outputpath)
perl $scriptpath -input $inputpath -output outputpath
```

When I execute this command from Powershell by passing the necessary arguments, I am getting expected result.
But on executing via web jobs, I am getting errors like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoJmj.png)

Do I need to modify my Powershell script?

Comment: 1) Please update your question to use code formatting (4 spaces indent). 2) Please do not paste a link to a picture of an error. Instead, please update your question and copy and paste the exact text of the error message.

Comment: You still need to update your question with the _text_ of the error message (not a link to a picture of the error).